# How to use scrollView in RelativeView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application I want use some views such as `ImageView`, `TextView`, `RecyclerView` and more ... in scroll view!

I write below codes but not show me `RecyclerView` !

**My codes :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/miniFullSearch_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size50"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/miniFullSearch_toolbarBack"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size30"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
            android:src="@drawable/back_arrow_image" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/miniFullSearch_toolbarText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/miniFullSearch_toolbarBack"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/search"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/lightGray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font14" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullSearchMini_celebritiesLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/miniFullSearch_toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullSearchMini_celebritiesHeaderLay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size50">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fullSearchMini_celebritiesHeaderTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding10"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/celebrities"
                android:textColor="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fullSearchMini_celebritiesHeaderLoadMore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding10"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fullSearchMini_celebritiesHeaderLoadMoreImage"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size20"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size20"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_next"
                    android:tint="@color/darkBlueGrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding5"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fullSearchMini_celebritiesHeaderLoadMoreImage"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/loadMore"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font14" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/fullSearchMini_celebritiesRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fullSearchMini_celebritiesHeaderLoadMore" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why not show me recyclerView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it like this :

```
<NestedScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout>
    //All other views
    <RecyclerView>
  </RelativeLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

Make sure you have only one child layout inside the nestedScrollView.

Second i would suggest you to do this

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recylerView,false);
```

Hope this helps.